# conversion constructor, base class as a parameter?

Tags: c++

If `Derived` derives from `Base`, does it make sense to define a conversion constructor like this?

```
Derived(const Base& b) : Base(b) {
    //...
}
```

Are there problems with the `Derived` copy constructor?

I'll specify my intent here. I have a Base class and three derived classes. I have objects for each derived class stored in lists, one for each type.
I then have a file in which some the objects are stored, but as the base class. A line in the file indicates which type of derived class corresponds.
My code should look in the correct list whether the object is present (using == operator inherited from the base class). 
Please tell me if there are better solutions as well.

Comment: What is your motivation for choosing to do this?  Is there a specific behavior you'd like?

Comment: You do have casting for this role. Any specific reason you want a constructor ?

Comment: I have a a base class and three derived classes. I need to load objects from a text file. In the file, the objects are stored as the base class, but a line indicates which derived class it is. I then need to create a `Derived` object. Don't know if I made myself clear, I have some problems with English.

Comment: @DumbCoder: Casting doesn't solve this. OP: This is perfectly fine if your `Derived` class is in a valid state when created from a `Base` object.

Comment: @Xeo - The OP added the extra bits later on, after the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what you're trying to achieve here but casting a base class object to a derived class one is almost certainly a bad idea.

If you have a collection of derived class objects stored as base class ones you don't need a "line in a file" identifying which type they actually are. Just define a virtual function in the base class (eg. GetType()) and implement it differently in each derived class. Or even better, to avoid the (if (obj.GetType() == ) style programming just have a single interface and provide different implementations in each derived class. The derived class knows perfectly well what it is and your top-level code probably doesn't need to know.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for the underlying problem is a factory method: `std::shared_ptr<Base> ReadObject(std::istream&);`. This method can read the "type" line from your file and create the appropriate type object.